# Location Opt-In Prompt

Tags: flutter, dart, onesignal

```
 void _handleSetLocationShared() {
print("Paylaşılan konumu true olarak ayarlama");
OneSignal.shared.setLocationShared(true);
```

}

```
 TableRow(children: [
         OneSignalButton("Paylaşılan Konumu Ayarla",
            _handleSetLocationShared, !_enableConsentButton)
      ])
```

[My OneSignal Inapp message image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3aTCl.png)

*
I Get Error In Apply The Error I Get: "Location Unavailable It seems there are no location services configured in this app. Please refer to the OneSignal documentation for more information.*
[Picture of the Error I Get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdQxi.png)

Answer (score 1):

Add the following code to debug/AndroidManifest.xml and profile/AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

Add the following code to the main.dart file

```
OneSignal.shared.addTrigger("location_prompt", "true");
```

and then set the image from OneSignal
[OneSignal image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/385iO.png)